# Adjust the polar coordinates for geom_text with coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a series of labels into a circle. I have it mostly there, but they're too tightly pressed together and I want to increase the radius so that they can spread out a bit. No matter what value I set for the "y" variable, they continue to clump together as below.

[image]

Here is what I've tried:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
    geom_text(data        =  hcdata,
              aes(x       =  x,
                  y       =  y+30,
                  label   =  label,
                  colour  =  factor(clust),
                  angle   =  angle),
              vjust       =  labelParams$vjust,
              hjust       =  labelParams$hjust,
              size        =  label.size,
              show.legend =  FALSE)

## orientation
p <- p +
      coord_polar(direction = 1) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL,
                         limits = c(0, nrow(hcdata))) +
      scale_y_reverse(breaks = ybreaks)

p
```

Data Preview:

```
> head(hcdata)
  x y            label clust    angle
1 1 0              UCF     7 447.1277
2 2 0    Virginia Tech     7 443.2979
3 3 0          Hofstra     7 439.4681
4 4 0 SUNY Stony Brook     7 435.6383
5 5 0          U Miami     7 431.8085
6 6 0 Eastern Virginia     6 427.9787
 
> str(labelParams)
List of 3
 $ angle: num [1:94] 447 443 439 436 432 ...
 $ hjust: num [1:94] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ vjust: num 0.5
```

My data for `hcdata` is here:

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 
62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 
78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 
94), y = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = c("UCF", "Virginia Tech", 
"Hofstra", "SUNY Stony Brook", "U Miami", "Eastern Virginia", 
"Temple", "Drexel", "Saint Louis", "NYMC", "Tufts", "Augusta", 
"Rutgers (RWJ)", "U Missouri", "U S Florida", "SUNY Buffalo", 
"U Kentucky", "West Virginia", "U Illinois", "U Missouri (Kansas City)", 
"Wayne State", "U Arizona", "SUNY Upstate", "Texas A&M", "Rutgers (Newark)", 
"UT Houston", "U Louisville", "Northwestern", "Columbia", "Vanderbilt", 
"Mount Sinai", "NYU", "Case Western", "Yale", "U Penn", "Johns Hopkins", 
"Harvard", "Duke", "WashU", "U Florida", "Stanford", "UVA", "Jefferson", 
"Rush", "U Rochester", "Baylor", "MUSC", "U Connecticut", "U Utah", 
"Georgetown", "U Chicago", "U Michigan", "Wake Forest", "Cornell", 
"Virginia Commonwealth", "U Pitt", "UC Irvine", "U Cincinnati", 
"Emory", "UCSD", "Ohio State", "George Washington", "UCLA", "UTSW", 
"Mayo", "Einstein", "USC (Keck)", "U Mass", "U Kansas", "U SC", 
"UTHSC", "U Arkansas", "Texas Tech", "U Oklahoma", "U New Mexico", 
"U Nebraska", "U Hawaii", "Dartmouth", "U Iowa", "U Wisconsin", 
"UT San Antonio", "UC Davis", "U Maryland", "U Vermont", "U Alabama", 
"Boston", "IndianaU", "Brown", "UNC Chapel Hill", "U Colorado", 
"U Washington", "OHSU", "U Minnesota", "UCSF"), clust = c(7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), angle = c(447.127659574468, 443.297872340426, 
439.468085106383, 435.63829787234, 431.808510638298, 427.978723404255, 
424.148936170213, 420.31914893617, 416.489361702128, 412.659574468085, 
408.829787234043, 405, 401.170212765958, 397.340425531915, 393.510638297872, 
389.68085106383, 385.851063829787, 382.021276595745, 378.191489361702, 
374.36170212766, 370.531914893617, 366.702127659575, 362.872340425532, 
359.042553191489, 355.212765957447, 351.382978723404, 347.553191489362, 
343.723404255319, 339.893617021277, 336.063829787234, 332.234042553192, 
328.404255319149, 324.574468085106, 320.744680851064, 316.914893617021, 
313.085106382979, 309.255319148936, 305.425531914894, 301.595744680851, 
297.765957446809, 293.936170212766, 290.106382978723, 286.276595744681, 
282.446808510638, 278.617021276596, 274.787234042553, 270.957446808511, 
447.127659574468, 443.297872340426, 439.468085106383, 435.63829787234, 
431.808510638298, 427.978723404255, 424.148936170213, 420.31914893617, 
416.489361702128, 412.659574468085, 408.829787234043, 405, 401.170212765957, 
397.340425531915, 393.510638297872, 389.68085106383, 385.851063829787, 
382.021276595745, 378.191489361702, 374.36170212766, 370.531914893617, 
366.702127659574, 362.872340425532, 359.042553191489, 355.212765957447, 
351.382978723404, 347.553191489362, 343.723404255319, 339.893617021277, 
336.063829787234, 332.234042553191, 328.404255319149, 324.574468085106, 
320.744680851064, 316.914893617021, 313.085106382979, 309.255319148936, 
305.425531914894, 301.595744680851, 297.765957446808, 293.936170212766, 
290.106382978723, 286.276595744681, 282.446808510638, 278.617021276596, 
274.787234042553, 270.957446808511)), row.names = c(NA, -94L), class = "data.frame")
```

Data for `labelParams` is here:

```
list(angle = c(447.127659574468, 443.297872340426, 439.468085106383, 
435.63829787234, 431.808510638298, 427.978723404255, 424.148936170213, 
420.31914893617, 416.489361702128, 412.659574468085, 408.829787234043, 
405, 401.170212765958, 397.340425531915, 393.510638297872, 389.68085106383, 
385.851063829787, 382.021276595745, 378.191489361702, 374.36170212766, 
370.531914893617, 366.702127659575, 362.872340425532, 359.042553191489, 
355.212765957447, 351.382978723404, 347.553191489362, 343.723404255319, 
339.893617021277, 336.063829787234, 332.234042553192, 328.404255319149, 
324.574468085106, 320.744680851064, 316.914893617021, 313.085106382979, 
309.255319148936, 305.425531914894, 301.595744680851, 297.765957446809, 
293.936170212766, 290.106382978723, 286.276595744681, 282.446808510638, 
278.617021276596, 274.787234042553, 270.957446808511, 447.127659574468, 
443.297872340426, 439.468085106383, 435.63829787234, 431.808510638298, 
427.978723404255, 424.148936170213, 420.31914893617, 416.489361702128, 
412.659574468085, 408.829787234043, 405, 401.170212765957, 397.340425531915, 
393.510638297872, 389.68085106383, 385.851063829787, 382.021276595745, 
378.191489361702, 374.36170212766, 370.531914893617, 366.702127659574, 
362.872340425532, 359.042553191489, 355.212765957447, 351.382978723404, 
347.553191489362, 343.723404255319, 339.893617021277, 336.063829787234, 
332.234042553191, 328.404255319149, 324.574468085106, 320.744680851064, 
316.914893617021, 313.085106382979, 309.255319148936, 305.425531914894, 
301.595744680851, 297.765957446808, 293.936170212766, 290.106382978723, 
286.276595744681, 282.446808510638, 278.617021276596, 274.787234042553, 
270.957446808511), hjust = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    vjust = 0.5)
```

**EDIT**: For whatever reason, I was able to make some progress by adding `geom_point` to the figure and setting it's `alpha=0` so that you can't see it. For whatever reason, the behavior of `geom_text` is different if there are other geom layers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you change label.size to see if you can find the solution.

```
label.size=1
```

[image]

Comment: Becomes sort of unreadable if you shrink the text.